# Entire Highchart API calling from JSON file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

I am trying to call entire highcharts API from my JSON file so that it will be easy for deployment.
so I have transform my entire data into JSON file
JSON file :

```
    { "chart" : { "type" : "line" },
  "legend" : [ { "layout" : "vertical" },
      { "floating" : true },
      { "backgroundColor" : "#FFFFFF" },
      { "align" : "right" },
      { "verticalAlign" : "top" },
      { "y" : 60 },
      { "x" : -60 }
    ],
  "series" : [ { "data" : [ 29.899999999999999,
            71.5,
            106.40000000000001,
            129.19999999999999,
            144.0,
            176.0,
            135.59999999999999,
            148.5,
            216.40000000000001,
            194.09999999999999,
            95.599999999999994,
            54.399999999999999
          ] } ],
  "xAxis" : { "categories" : [ "Jan",
          "Feb",
          "Mar",
          "Apr",
          "May",
          "Jun",
          "Jul",
          "Aug",
          "Sep",
          "Oct",
          "Nov",
          "Dec"
        ] }
}
```

but it was showing error of RENDERTO not found.
(I tried adding that in JSON file as well), but its not working so I want to know how can I plot my highcharts in 'Container' my html is as follows:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
   function loadJson() {
 $(document).ready(function()
 {
 //alert("inside");
 var chart;
 var url = "val1.json";
    var seriesData ;
         $.getJSON(url, function(data)
         {
         seriesData = data;
         alert(seriesData);

        chart = new Highcharts.Chart(seriesData);
    });

});
}

  </script>
</head>
<body onload="loadJson();">
  <div id="container">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

HOW Can I make a "Renderto" call in HTML or JSON file.
any help is appreciated as I am novice in highcharts as well as JSON 
Thank YOu

Comment: if possible can you plz create a working JSFIDDLE which describes your exact problem ?

Answer (score 0):

if you use a highcharts 3.* there is no need to use renderTo.

instead you can render as below

```
$("#container").highcharts({yorObj});
```

refer highchart api http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set the renderTo option correctly:

```
 { "chart" : { "type" : "line", "renderTo":"container" },
```

The alternative way is to render onto the jquery selector:

```
 $('#container').highcharts(chartJsonObject);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    function loadJson() {
 $(document).ready(function()
 {
 //alert("inside");
 var chart;
 var url = "val1.json";
 var seriesData ;
   $.getJSON(url, function(data)
   {
  var chartoptions = data;
   chartoptions.chart.renderTo = 'container';
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart(chartoptions);
    });

});
}
```

I was not able to plot the graph because the code was not getting the reference to the container, so I set it using the chartOptions as that was available outside my chart settings.

Hope it will help the learning players.
and Thanks for the one who helped.
Have a nice coding week......